# solve_ivp on a differential equation containing squared functions

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I was trying to solve (x’(t))^2+ax^2(t)-b=0 numerically in python. I know I can use scipy’s solve_ivp for simpler equations by defining the functions like :

```
def f(t, y):
   return y ** 2
```

which would represent the equation y’(t)=y**2. How can I write the first equation like this? I’m aware that potentially the equation can be simplified with a substituition (maybe y=x^2 or something) but I’m just interested in solving it directly (and numerically) in this case.

I tried naively solving the first equation for x’(t), meaning the definition of f in python contains math.sqrt(). This gives me a domain error (at some stage the input is negative presumably). This error occurred with many different values of an and b so I’m at a loss for how to continue.

Comment: Please correct the typo: "which would represent the equation f’(t)=t^2". That would represent the equation y'(t) = y**2. What are the initial conditions? What are example values of `a` and `b`? Although it's clear why the error is occuring, please include a MRE of the error so others don't have to start from scratch. It's already arguable that this is a math question and not a programming question (how to transform it into the form required by solve_ivp), so if you'd like an answer on this site, it's best to show that you've done some work on your own and your question is about the code.

Comment: Hi @MattHaberland, thanks for your comment. I’ve corrected the typo. The initial conditions can just be y(0)=0 but I found it wasn’t really relevant to my question. Likewise, an and b are just arbitrary, but I tried a=b=1 when attempting the solution with square root. I don’t believe it’s arguable that the question is strictly related to math as I’m asking if my equation is representable in python and then solvable numerically.

Comment: If indeed the function is difficult to represent in python, please give this as an answer. My own work is (albeit naively) trying directly substituting f**2 into solve_ivp and attempting to define the function by “math.sqrt(1 - y**2)”. The former gives a TypeError as there’s no operand between ** and functions, and the latter either gives a domain error (negative sqrt as I stated in the question) or gives a straight line plot - which I find very strange.

Comment: And if I’ve made a mistake with y**2 or t**2 I tried both and it’s either a straight line plot or an error with the domain of sqrt. Sorry for my weak understanding of how the function is defined, just let me know if you need any more information :)

Comment: I've undeleted an answer I wrote yesterday that just addresses the type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODE with non-smooth right sides can have defects under numerical solution.

In the given situation an exact solution can have segments where it is constant, `x'=0`, and other segments where it solves `x''+ax=0`, and these modes can switch at points where both mode equations are simultaneously satisfied. This gives an infinity of solutions.

So it would be best if you could select the solution behavior from the start and solve an ODE with less singularities.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I’ll try making the ODE linear before trying to solve it via this method then.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that you can follow your approach of taking the square root, but making sure the values are complex to begin with to avoid the domain error.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def f(t, x, a, b):
    return np.sqrt(b - a*x**2)
    # return -np.sqrt(b - a*x**2)

a = 2 + 0j
b = 1 + 0j
t0, tf = 0, 10
y0 = [1 + 0j]

res = solve_ivp(f, (t0, tf), y0, args=(a, b))  # solves successfully
```

Based on experiments in Mathematica, this doesn't seem to produce a correct solution, though. But then this becomes more of a math question, which you might ask on the [Mathematics SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).